# QuickFIX/J message cracking problem - onMessage() handler not being called

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

I have problem on QuickFIX/J message cracking. My message handler after message cracking is not working.

I have implemented message cracking as on link (codes are below) https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/receiving_messages.html

When I debugged the code the *invoker* instance on library side is not found. So `UnsupportedMessageType` is thrown.

*Debugged code:*

[image]

**Project Settings/Codes:**

*gradle dependencies:*

```
implementation group: 'org.quickfixj', name: 'quickfixj-all', version: '2.3.0'
```

*Initialization:*

```
SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Server.cfg"));
MessageStoreFactory storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
LogFactory logFactory = new FileLogFactory(settings);
MessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();
SocketAcceptor socketAcceptor = new SocketAcceptor(fixApplication, storeFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);
```

*Acceptor code:*

```
...
public class FixApplication extends MessageCracker implements Application {
   ...

    @Override
    public void fromApp(Message message, SessionID sessionId) throws FieldNotFound, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType {
        crack(message, sessionId);
    }

    public void onMessage(quickfix.fix50sp2.NewOrderSingle order, SessionID sessionId) throws FieldNotFound, IncorrectTagValue {
        // expecting message cracker will call this handler on NewOrderSingle message
    }
...
}
```

As seen I am using `quickfix.fix50sp2.NewOrderSingle`.
This is the sample transaction for NewOrderSingle. I got `Unsupported Message Type` error.

```
< 8=FIXT.1.1|9=132|35=D|49=SENDER_ID|56=TARGET_ID|34=2|52=20210818-20:46:50|11=899094438|21=1|55=ERICB.ST|54=1|60=20210818-20:46:50|40=2|44=50|38=1000|10=117|

> 8=FIXT.1.1|9=106|35=j|34=2|49=TARGET_ID|52=20210818-20:46:50.096|56=SENDER_ID|45=2|58=Unsupported Message Type|372=D|380=3|10=000|
```

**Config File:**

```
[default]
FileStorePath=server/data/acceptor
FileLogPath=server/log/acceptor
ConnectionType=acceptor
SenderCompID=XXX
SocketConnectHost=localhost
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=5
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
TransportDataDictionary=spec/FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary=spec/FIX50SP2.xml
UseDataDictionary=Y
ValidOrderTypes=1,2
```

**Question:**

- How can I fix this issue? So after `crack(quickfix.Message message, SessionID sessionID)` operation my `onMessage(quickfix.fix50sp2.NewOrderSingle order, SessionID sessionId)` handler can be called.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are really using a FIX50SP2 `NewOrderSingle`? It is not visible from your sample message. Technically you can transmit any FIX version via `FIXT` transport. What does your config look like? What happens if you added `onMessage` handlers for FIX50 and FIX50SP1? Does one of them get called?

Comment: @Christoph John, I added NewOrderSingle onMessage for fix50, fix44 also. But result is same (invoker is null and *UnsupportedMessageType* is thrown).

**Acceptor config is like that:**
```
[default]
FileStorePath=server/data/acceptor
FileLogPath=server/log/acceptor
ConnectionType=acceptor
SenderCompID=XXX
SocketConnectHost=localhost
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=5
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
TransportDataDictionary=spec/FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary=spec/FIX50SP2.xml
UseDataDictionary=Y
ValidOrderTypes=1,2
```

Comment: Please add some code to the question on how you initialize your application. Especially which kind of `MessageFactory` you are using.

Comment: Added initialization codes. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, looks good to me. Could you call `message.getClass().getCanonicalName()` in your `fromApp()`?

Comment: *message.getClass().getCanonicalName()* returns *quickfix.Message*

Comment: Added extracted sample codes (gives same result) to repo: https://github.com/taneryilmaz/QuickFixDemo

Comment: @Christoph John. I think the problem is importing generic MessageCracker (```quickfix.MessageCracker```) when using ```import quickfix.*;```.

I have imported ```quickfix.fix50sp2.MessageCracker```. But this time I have encountered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074850/quickfix-message-cannot-be-cast-to-quickfix-fix50sp2-message problem. I have copied DefaultMessageFactory to a custom factory (like FixMessageFactory.java) and did that change on link. Still same error.

Comment: That code from the other question is outdated and it should work without adaptations on recent QFJ versions. I cannot spot the problem in your code, it should work. ;) I'll think about it again. Maybe you can update your project with the current code in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related with local character settings. I changed local language settings to US on Windows and problem is solved.

*The details are below:*

When loading factory messages on `DeafultMessageFactory` class names are coverted to

- *quickfix.fıx...MessageFactory*       <-- attention: *fıx* not *fix*

should be

- *quickfix.fix...MessageFactory*

[image]

When a raw fix message is converted to related fix message (as `quickfix.fix41.NewOrderSingle`) on factory it is not converted exactly. Instead generic `quickfix.Message` is returned.

[image]

@Christoph John, thanks for your helps.

Comment: Wow that is very strange. But good that you found the cause.

Comment: Could this be a general problem with the Turkish locale?

Comment: Yes. So I changed the locale language settings to English.